# Android thread doesn't wait just runs once

Tags: java, android, multithreading, usb

I've created a broadcasting service that contains runnables that are supposed to wait for input, it runs the first runnable inline at least once but doesn't add any of the others nor waits and listens.

```
public class MainService extends Service {

//  Manager device;
    Emitter emitter;

    RFIDPhidget device;

    Service service;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }   

     @Override
     public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
         // For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here...
         Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
//        LinearLayout lin_out = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lineout);
//        lin_out.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(this, " Service CREATED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try
        {
            com.phidgets.usb.Manager.Initialize(this);

            //device = new Manager();
            device = new RFIDPhidget();

            service = this;

            emitter = new Emitter(this);

            device.addAttachListener(new AttachListener() {
                public void attached(final AttachEvent attachEvent) {
                    AttachEventHandler handler = new AttachEventHandler((RFIDPhidget)attachEvent.getSource(), service);    
                    handler.run();
                    synchronized(handler) {

                        try {
                            handler.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            device.addDetachListener(new DetachListener() {
                public void detached(final DetachEvent detachEvent) {
                    DetachEventHandler handler = new DetachEventHandler((RFIDPhidget)detachEvent.getSource(), service);    
                    handler.run();
                    synchronized(handler) {
                        try {
                            handler.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            device.addTagGainListener(new TagGainListener() {
                public void tagGained(TagGainEvent oe) {
                    TagGainedHandler handler = new TagGainedHandler(oe, emitter);    
                    handler.run();
                    synchronized(handler)
                    {
                        try {
                            handler.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            device.addTagLossListener(new TagLossListener() {
                public void tagLost(TagLossEvent oe) {
                    TagLossHandler handler = new TagLossHandler(oe, emitter);    
                    handler.run();
                    synchronized(handler)
                    {
                        try {
                            handler.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });


            device.openAny();
        } catch (PhidgetException pe) {
            pe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            device.close();
        } catch (PhidgetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        com.phidgets.usb.Manager.Uninitialize();
    }
}
```

I used to run this whole code in an activity and use, `runOnUIThread(handler);` for each listener variable 'handler'but since this isn't possible in services i started just using `handler.run();`.

It runs the AttachEventHandler once at least, it doesn't run the other ones nor wait for it. Here is an example of the code inside the listeners.

```
public class AttachEventHandler implements Runnable { 
    RFIDPhidget device;
    Service main_service;

    public AttachEventHandler(RFIDPhidget device, Service main_service) {
        this.device = device;
        this.main_service = main_service;
    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            device.setAntennaOn(true);
            device.setLEDOn(true);
            Toast.makeText(main_service, "Hello " + device.getDeviceName() + ", Serial " + Integer.toString(device.getSerialNumber()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } catch (PhidgetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Notify that we're done
        synchronized(this) {
            this.notify();
        }
    }
```

All of the listeners are identical accept for what happens in their try functions.

I need help figuring out how to let them wait or at least keep running in the background, that's the whole reason I moved to a service so I wouldn't be UI dependent.

If you need any further information don't be afraid to ask.

Comment: there is no thread inthe code you posted

Comment: Attention: An Android Service runs on the "main" thread unless you (the developer) code it to start one or use ... what was it? IntentService - I believe.

Comment: From [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) : "The IntentService does the following:
•Creates a default worker thread that executes all intents delivered to onStartCommand() separate from your application's main thread.
•Creates a work queue that passes one intent at a time to your onHandleIntent() implementation, so you never have to worry about multi-threading.
•Stops the service after all start requests have been handled, so you never have to call stopSelf().
•..."

Comment: @Fildor Could you show an example more accurately applying to my situation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke your handlers like new Thread(handler).start(); instead of handler.run();

because run, executes in same thread, so you won't get wait/notify

Comment: `Thread t = new Thread(handler); t.start();` gives me this error.
AndroidRuntime(2874): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()